# Isotope.js and Webpack - possible?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jquery-isotope, webpack

I'm trying to get my webpack setup working with isotope.js. The problem I'm running into is that when webpack goes to compile, it can't find a window and throws an error.

Tried the following:

*In myfile.js*

`import Isotope from 'isotope-layout';`

*webpack.config.js*

`loaders: [{
   test: /isotope-layout/,
   loader: 'imports?this=>window!isotope-layout'
  }`

but it throws the following error:

```
/ipb/node_modules/lodash/index.js" as it exceeds the max of "100KB".

/Users/user/Development/ipb/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:206
                    throw e;
                          ^
ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/user/Development/ipb/node_modules/isotope-layout/js/isotope.js:60:4)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at DependenciesBlock.loadPitch (/Users/user/Development/ipb/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:193:17)
    at DependenciesBlock.loadPitch (/Users/user/Development/ipb/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:186:21)
    at DependenciesBlock.loadPitch (/Users/user/Development/ipb/node_modules/webpack/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:223:61)
```

What am I doing wrong here, or what would be the better way to get this accomplished?

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
var $ = require('jquery');
var jQueryBridget = require('jquery-bridget');
var Isotope = require('isotope-layout');
// make Isotope a jQuery plugin
jQueryBridget( 'isotope', Isotope, $ );
// now you can use $().isotope()
$('.grid').isotope({// options...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something along

```
var Isotope = require('imports?$=jquery!isotope-layout/dist/isotope.pkgd');
```

That seems to work for me. Note that this solution depends on [imports-loader](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imports-loader);

You can likely push this to your Webpack configuration rather than solving it inline. Just hoping this answer points you to the right direction.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. I'm not using jquery in this project, but I assume I can just remove the part of the imports statement that refers to it, correct?

Comment: @afithings The problem is that Isotope relies on jQuery. You can likely inject it using some other ways. This is just something that worked for me on my quick test.

Comment: I don't believe it does require jquery. Its site shows jquery and vanilla js examples of implementation.

Comment: Ah, good point! Yes, I think in that case you can make it work without jQuery. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work. When I try to apply it to my webpack.config file, it throws an error, saying `var isotope-layout/dist/isotope.pkgd.js = require("isotope-layout/dist/isotope.pkgd.js");` which obviously isn't right. I'm calling it in my code as `import Isotope from 'isotope-layout'`.

My entry in webpack.config looks like this:

`{ test: /isotope-layout/, loader: 'imports?isotopelayout/dist/isotope.pkgd.js' },`

Answer (score 0):

#### 2023 Update

[@metafizzy](https://github.com/metafizzy), its 3 years and no update on isotope. Is it falling under abandoned projects. I don't know. Just my opinion. However, i feel it's a great project that should be supported. In case you want to use as i do, you can import it as Module loaders i.e. in webpack as follow:

```
Install
# yarn add isotope-layout

// main.js
var Isotope = require('isotope-layout');
var iso = new Isotope( '.grid', {
  // options...
});
```

Read more in the docs: https://isotope.metafizzy.co/extras.html#webpack
If you run into error like: `cannot find module globby/index.js`, restart your app and run `yarn install` followed by `yarn add isotope-layout`.